# CardMedia height material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im struggling trying to change the height of the image inside the CardMedia

Im setting the style with

```
const style = {
  height: 32,
};
```

and using it in

```
<CardMedia
  overlay={<CardTitle title="Title"/>}
  mediaStyle={style}>

  <img src="imgUrl" />
</CardMedia>
```

but the height of the image remains the same. The only thing that happens is that the overlay with the title moves to the top. I've tried all the CardMedia properties but i havent succeeded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to apply the styles on the image directly:

```
<CardMedia overlay={<CardTitle title="Title"/>}>
  <img src={imgUrl} style={style}/>
</CardMedia>
```

Set desired `width` and `height` of the image, `Card` will adjust to the image.

Comment: Thanks man! This solved it - However it got me thinking. Isn't it better to style in CSS instead of doing this inline styling of react components?

Comment: That's a very good question @c-poulsen! I was never fan of inline styling, I would recommend you to take a look at "CSS Modules", e.g. start reading about it here https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/ :-)

Comment: That seems interesting :) Thanks once again

Comment: Forgot to mention about the current hype in styling in React components: ["Styled Components"](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

Comment: Hey, this kind of worked for me but I see this warning in the console `Material-UI: either 'image' or 'src' property must be specified.` Any idea whats going on?

Comment: @Annjawn you can simply handle that warning by initializing the corresponding state in the constructor, like: `this.state = { images: 'some default values' }`

Comment: tyhis does not work for me : "img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML"`

Answer (score 1):

try using style instead of mediaStyle, like

```
const Style = {
  height: 32,
};

    <CardMedia
      overlay={<CardTitle title="Title"/>}
      style={Style}>

      <img src="imgUrl" />
    </CardMedia>
```

Comment: As i wrote: I've tried all the properties including style. It doesn't work

Comment: @c-poulsen then check whether your components overlaps with other components. press Ctrl + Shift + C and hover over your components, you might find whats wrong with your code.

Comment: It worked for me, but I've used image={imgUrl} attribute in CardMedia instead of <img></img>